# Is it possible to use a cloned operating system through an external disk connected by USB?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, operating-systems, clone

I'm trying to clone a laptop's disk using an external hard drive in order to then use it on a different computer. The problem is that while the external HDD has enough space (1TB), the other computer doesn't. Hence the question -- is it possible to clone the entire disk (dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows) to the external 1TB hard drive, and then boot and use the OS directly from the external disk plugged in by USB, and if so, is it a good idea?

Comment: Its possible to run both windows and linux from a USB device, so it could work. If the new system has different hardware then its probably not going to be a very smooth transition. Assuming you don't delete the source of the clone, give it a go since the data is safe anyway?

Comment: Not a good idea : Windows performance on USB will be atrocious and it will not be activated. Perhaps you should tell us more about the problem on the other computer.